# Creating a App Engine Datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using google app engine and I'm trying to insert a entity/table using the code:

```
class Tu(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    presentation = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

.
.
.

```
a = Tu('teste', 'bla bla bla bla')
        a.votes = 5
        a.put()
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: Expected Model type; received teste (is str)
```

I'm following this doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities and I don't see where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a model in that way, you need to use keyword  arguments for all attributes of your model. Here is a snippet of the `__init__` signature from `db.Model`, from which your `Tu` model inherits:

```
def __init__(self,
               parent=None,
               key_name=None,
               _app=None,
               _from_entity=False,
               **kwds):
    """Creates a new instance of this model.

    To create a new entity, you instantiate a model and then call put(),
    which saves the entity to the datastore:

       person = Person()
       person.name = 'Bret'
       person.put()

    You can initialize properties in the model in the constructor with keyword
    arguments:

       person = Person(name='Bret')

    # continues
```

When you say `a = Tu('teste', 'bla bla bla bla')`, since you aren't providing keyword arguments and are instead passing them as positional arguments, `teste` is assigned to the `parent` argument in the `__init__` (and `bla bla bla bla` to the `key_name`) and since that argument needs an object of type `Model` (which I'm assuming you don't have), you get that error. Assuming you are instead trying to add those items as `title` and `presentation`, you would say (as @DanielRoseman already succinctly stated :) ):

```
a = Tu(title='teste', presentation='bla bla bla bla')
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs you link to all use keyword arguments:

```
a = Tu(title='tests', presentation='blablablah')
```

If you use positional arguments, the first argument is interpreted as the parent, which needs to be of type Model or Key.